Properly rasterize a triangles edges using barycentric algorithm
In an attempt to add a z-buffer to a custom 3D rendering engine, I need to use a barycentric algorithm to interpolate the depth of each point inside a triangle. While this approach works, the algorithm that I found seems to have trouble calculating edges properly.
In green (left) you can see a triangle rendered using a previous algorithm.
In red (right) you can see a triangle rendered using the barycentric algorithm.
If you overlay the two, you can easily see that the barycentric algorithm does not render edges properly.
Here are the coordinates of the triangles (rendered at resolution 320x240, the top right one is just offset by 50 pixels)
{50, 20}
{70, 60}
{30, 50}



Here is an other example of a rotating triangle (the correct edges are rendered in red this time)


Here are the two algorithm I used, written in C
void barycentric(vec3f a, vec3f b, vec3f c, vec3f p, float *u, float *v, float *w) {
    vec3f v0 = vec3f_sub(b,a), v1 = vec3f_sub(c,a), v2 = vec3f_sub(p,a);
    float d00 = vec3f_dot_product(v0, v0);
    float d01 = vec3f_dot_product(v0, v1);
    float d11 = vec3f_dot_product(v1, v1);
    float d20 = vec3f_dot_product(v2, v0);
    float d21 = vec3f_dot_product(v2, v1);
    float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
    *v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
    *w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
    *u = 1.0f - *v - *w;
}

void drawBarycentricTriangle(uint32_t pixels[], vec3f a, vec3f b, vec3f c, uint32_t color) {
    int min_x = (int)round(fminf(a.x, fminf(b.x, c.x)));
    int max_x = (int)round(fmaxf(a.x, fmaxf(b.x, c.x)));
    int min_y = (int)round(fminf(a.y, fminf(b.y, c.y)));
    int max_y = (int)round(fmaxf(a.y, fmaxf(b.y, c.y)));

    // iterate over the bounding box of the triangle
    for (int y = min_y; y <= max_y; y++) {
        for (int x = min_x; x <= max_x; x++) {
            vec3f p = {x, y, 0};
            float u, v, w;
            barycentric(a, b, c, p, &u, &v, &w);
            // only draw pixels if the points are inside the triangle
            if (u >= 0 && v >= 0 && w >= 0) {
                drawPixel(pixels, x, y, color);
            }
        }
    }
}

void drawTriangle(uint32_t pixels[], vec2i P0, vec2i P1, vec2i P2, uint32_t color) {
    // sort the points by y-coordinate
    if (P1.y < P0.y) { swap(&P1.y, &P0.y); swap(&P1.x, &P0.x); }
    if (P2.y < P0.y) { swap(&P2.y, &P0.y); swap(&P2.x, &P0.x); }
    if (P2.y < P1.y) { swap(&P2.y, &P1.y); swap(&P2.x, &P1.x); }
    
    // degenerate triangle if all points on the same horizontal line
    if (P0.y == P1.y && P1.y == P2.y) return; 
    if (P0.x<0 && P1.x<0 && P2.x<0) return;
    if (P0.y<0 && P1.y<0 && P2.y<0) return;

    float invslope1, invslope2, curx1, curx2;
    if (P0.y == P1.y) {
        // flat-top triangle
        if (P1.x < P0.x) { swap(&P1.x, &P0.x); }
        invslope1 = (float)(P2.x - P0.x) / (P2.y - P0.y);
        invslope2 = (float)(P2.x - P1.x) / (P2.y - P1.y);
        curx1 = P2.x;
        curx2 = P2.x;
        for (int y = P2.y; y >= P0.y; y--) {
            int start = (int)round(curx1);
            int end = (int)round(curx2);
            if (start > end) { swap(&start, &end); }
            for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
                drawPixel(pixels, x, y, color);
            }
            curx1 -= invslope1;
            curx2 -= invslope2;
        }
    } else if (P1.y == P2.y) {
        // flat-bottom triangle
        if (P2.x < P1.x) { swap(&P2.x, &P1.x); }
        invslope1 = (float)(P1.x - P0.x) / (P1.y - P0.y);
        invslope2 = (float)(P2.x - P0.x) / (P2.y - P0.y);
        curx1 = P0.x;
        curx2 = P0.x;
        for (int y = P0.y; y <= P1.y; y++) {
            int start = (int)round(curx1);
            int end = (int)round(curx2);
            if (start > end) { swap(&start, &end); }
            for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
                drawPixel(pixels, x, y, color);
            }
            curx1 += invslope1;
            curx2 += invslope2;
        }
    } else {
        // general case: split into a flat-top and flat-bottom triangle
        vec2i P3 = { P0.x + (int)((float)(P1.y - P0.y) / (P2.y - P0.y) * (P2.x - P0.x)), P1.y };
        invslope1 = (float)(P1.x - P0.x) / (P1.y - P0.y);
        invslope2 = (float)(P3.x - P0.x) / (P3.y - P0.y);
        curx1 = P0.x;
        curx2 = P0.x;
        for (int y = P0.y; y <= P1.y; y++) {
            int start = (int)round(curx1);
            int end = (int)round(curx2);
            if (start > end) { swap(&start, &end); }
            for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
                drawPixel(pixels, x, y, color);
            }
            curx1 += invslope1;
            curx2 += invslope2;
        }
        invslope1 = (float)(P2.x - P1.x) / (P2.y - P1.y);
        invslope2 = (float)(P2.x - P3.x) / (P2.y - P3.y);
        curx1 = P2.x;
        curx2 = P2.x;
        for (int y = P2.y; y >= P1.y; y--) {
            int start = (int)round(curx1);
            int end = (int)round(curx2);
            if (start > end) { swap(&start, &end); }
            for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
                drawPixel(pixels, x, y, color);
            }
            curx1 -= invslope1;
            curx2 -= invslope2;
        }
    }
}

In my engine this is what using the barycentric algorithm do:


And with the other triangle algorithm:

After doing some research online, my algorithm looks correct. Can anyone help me identify where the issue is and how to fix it?

"If you overlay the two, you can easily see that the barycentric algorithm does not render edges properly." I only see there's a difference; either one could be wrong. Besides, the difference is so subtle that it could be rounding direction (will you round 2.5 to 2 or to 3?), making both correct. Please supply sample coordinates to reproduce the issue.

I would say that the barycentric version is correct and looks better, while your original version is a little weird due to its axis bias.

@RuudHelderman I updated the post to include images that better portray the issue, showing why i think the other algorithm is correct, as well as the triangles coordinates
I also thought it was a rounding/precision issue, but i cannot find what causes it (removing the round() from the barycentric function doesn't change anything).

@MattTimmermans I also think the barycentric algorithm looks better on single triangles, but if you look at the images i added, it shows that it doesnt look right in a 3d space.
